Theorem of Constructive Dilemmas
I saw a theorem in my book that 1) $(p\to q)\wedge (r\to s)\equiv (p\wedge r)\to (q\wedge s)$ and 2) $(p\to q)\wedge (r\to s)\equiv (p\vee r)\to (q\vee s)$. I can prove second item but I can’t prove another one
Who can help me?
I saw the Constructive Dilemma, but I guess my question is more than difficult and i can’t conclude the result.

Only one direction of what you have labelled by (1) holds. Namely, $(p\to q) \wedge (r\to s)$ implies $(p\wedge r)\to (q\wedge s)$. It can be proved straightforwardly by supposing the premise, then supposing the antecedent $(p\wedge r)$ of the conclusion and reasoning from there.
To show that the other direction fails, consider the following truth value assignment.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
p& q & r & s & (p\wedge r)\to (q\wedge s) & (p\to q) \wedge (r\to s) \\ \hline
 T&F & F& T & T & F\\ \hline
\end{array}
This is an assignment where the premise is true but the conclusion is false, which shows that $(p\wedge r)\to (q\wedge s)$ does not imply $(p\to q) \wedge (r\to s)$. (If it's not quite clear how I computed the truth values, it is worth playing around with the truth tables for these expressions!)

Thank you, and can you prove (1)?
